# How to invoke a method with generic return type in java

Tags: java, generics, dynamic, types, generic-programming

I want to have a method returning a generic type. Let's say I have a parent class and 10 child classes. The parent class does not have any method defined and the child classes have different functions (none of them in common). I want to create an object of child class depending on some input. (can't create parent object since I cannot call the method of the classes). So I want to write a function that creates object in it and returns in main function. And I want to catch the T as return type. How do I invoke from main.

```
public static <T> T fun() {
    if (some condition) {
        return new Class1();
    } else {
        return new Class2();
    }
}
```

How do I invoke a function for correct class?

```
Class xyz = fun();
```

Comment: Isn't it obvious that you'd do that by making "some condition" either true or false?

Comment: That is not valid Java, since the method is missing a return type. It also doesn't work because neither `Class1` nor `Class2` is compatible with `T`, assuming you meant to return type `T`. If return type is not supposed to be `T`, then what's the point of `T`?

Comment: From looking at the code there, my guess is that you don't fully understand generics and what they can do. What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: what I want to do is return an object of either class1 or class2 and assign it to an object in another function.

Comment: I want to return type T. I have added T as the return type and yes I am new to generics

Comment: I have given more description about the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should pass as parameter the Class type what you want to use as response

```
public <T> T getAsObject(Class<T> clazz) {
    T bean = null;
    try {
        // do whatever you want to assign bean
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            bean = clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // some log
        }
    }
    return bean;
}
```

So you can use it with classes that inherit it from class that is used as parameter

For example:

```
public abstract class Parent {

    public Parent() {
    }

    public abstract void doit();
}

public class Child1 extends Parent {

    @Override
    public void doit() {
        // do something
    }
}

public class Child2 extends Parent {

    @Override
    public void doit() {
        // do other something
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
Parent parent = getAsObject(Child1.class);
// or 
Parent parent2 = getAsObject(Child2.class);
```